# What 1st Season Episodes in Babylon 5 are "Required" to Follow the Main Arc?

Tags: babylon-5, continuity

I was a fan of B5 even before it premiered, back when JMS was on GEnie and dropping hints to us (in the form of posts saying nothing more than "Eep!") that his special project was green-lighted.

I'm re-watching B5 with my girlfriend now and she's frustrated with the first season.  She feels like it's moving VERY slow and that it's taking a long time to develop the characters.  I do remember that by the middle of season 2 (specifically "The Coming of Shadows") that all the characters were so strongly developed that their complexities showed.

But my girlfriend is not as patient with the slower development in the 1st season as I am (I know even JMS has acknowledged that he felt he moved too slowly in season 1 because he took too long to introduce everything).

With that in mind, it'd help a lot if, when re-watching this show with her, I could let her skip the episodes that aren't arc related and don't give us information that matters later on.  There are some episodes I remember that were quite powerful (like "Believers") that I still want to show her, but I'd like to know which episodes she could skip so we can move through the 1st season faster.

So what 1st season episodes of Babylon 5 can be skipped without it hurting one's enjoyment of the show and the overall story arc?

Comment: If she doesn't like season 1, just wait until she learns that _Gray 17 is Missing_.

Comment: Sometimes I wish _Gray 17 is Missing_ was missing...

Comment: I think skipping episodes in an arc series is a bad idea - even if the episodes are not necessarily part of the arc. There is usually significant character development, and in most cases, there is still at least a thread of main arc through even the most tangential episodes. That said, _Gray 17 is Missing_ is truly awful, and I feel sorry for Robert Englund.

Comment: @HorusKol: I'd love to include all episodes, but she's frustrated and what appeals to her in a show or movie is characterizations, but if the plot is intriguing enough, that will do.  Unfortunately, something like the mystery of why Sinclair lost 24 hours and the Minbarri surrendered is not enough when she didn't see enough of Sinclair's character to care much about him in the first place.  So I'm hoping skipping the ones that aren't part of the arc will make things move fast enough she'll develop an interest.  If that works, we can go back and watch the others later.

Comment: but without Eyes, the B4 episodes make less sense...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ones that can be dropped are...

- TKO
- Grail
- Eyes
- Legacies

Those 4 really create a drag on the first season since they're grouped together and aren't all that good. There are some arc tidbits in each but may be better viewed after you get into the show.

Kind of middle of the road episodes, not essential though.

- Infection
- The Parliament of Dreams
- War Prayer
- By Any Means Necessary
- Born to the Purple

Really good episodes but not arc essential

- Deathwalker
- Believers

Story Arc essential ones

- Midnight on the Firing Line
- Soul Hunter
- And the Sky Full of Stars
- Survivors
- Signs and Portents
- A Voice in the Wilderness
- Babylon Squared
- The Quality of Mercy
- Chrysalis

Comment: Just watch the Story Arc essential episodes and move on to season 2. That's what I did and you won't miss much and it will greatly increase your enjoyment of the series.

Comment: Deathwalker and Believers have tie ins to later. Deathwalker establishes the Dilgar war, which is referenced in some later episodes and frequently in Crusade. Believers establishes certain elements of Dr. Franklin that help explain his actions in season 4. I recall also there's a flashback to it in a later episode.

Comment: @aramis - Yes, all of them, even the less than good episodes, have various bits of arc and character development in them that will be important later on. For example, Adira in Born to the Purple drives Londo in a certain direction later. TKO also does some foreshadowing and develops Ivanova. That said, the first season has its slow spots as compared to the fast pace of 2-4.

Comment: Born to the Purple is one of my favorite season 1 episodes. It's an excellent character study.

Comment: I'd actually consider Born to the Purple an arc-essential episode; it tells us so much that will matter later about Londo.

Comment: Mind War is missing from this answer. I think it ought to be arc-essential episode given that it's the first appearance of Bester and Catherine's expedition has the first clues that there are "things we don't understand" out there. Plus The Lurker's Guide calls it a "WHAM!" episode that advances the storyline.

Comment: Londo's relationship with Adira is pretty important, I wouldn't skip that one. +1 anyway.

Comment: As someone who watched the series on airing (pre-DVR days), I didn't really get into it, or realize there was any kind of an arc whatsoever, until the last two eps of S1. IMHO you could just watch those, and ep 3 (Midnight) to learn the characters, and you'd be fine.

Comment: TKO has only a single valuable sentence.  "Hey Michael - watch your back!"

Answer (score 4):

I'd broadly agree with [jrankcarr](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3147/jfrankcarr)'s list, but it might be useful to know that [The Lurker's Guide](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/) has an [episode list](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/reference/episodes.html) where the "WHAM!" episodes are highlighted in bold.

For season 1, they are:

- ["The Gathering"](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/000.html) (0x01, but ignore how cheesy bits of it are, particularly the terrible make-up)
- ["Mind War"](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/006.html) (1x06)
- ["And the Sky Full of Stars"](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/008.html) (1x08)
- ["Signs and Portents"](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/013.html) (1x13 and the episode whose title is the season title)
- "A Voice in the Wilderness" ([1x18](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/018.html) and [1x19](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/019.html))
- ["Babylon Squared"](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/020.html) (1x20)
- ["Chrysalis"](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/022.html) (1x22)

Personally, I would definitely add ["Survivors"](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/011.html) (1x11) and ["Soul Hunter"](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/002.html) (1x02) to that list. And I too have a soft spot for ["Born to the Purple"](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/003.html) (1x03).

I remember there being a *B5* marathon at Cambridge University and them posting their episode list to [umtsb5](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/uk.media.tv.sf.babylon5) back when I was at uni (not at Cambridge), but I can't find the post. I did find [this post (dated 1996)](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/uk.media.tv.sf.babylon5/Yz8r3lN_XqQ/spaeiaB956MJ), though, which suggests:

- ["Midnight on the Firing Line"](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/001.html) (1x01) *"great way to introduce the characters"*
- ["Mind War"](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/006.html) (1x06) and/or ["And the Sky Full of Stars"](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/008.html) (1x08) *"if you are taking your time"*
- ["Signs and Portents"](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/013.html) (1x13)
- "A Voice in the Wilderness" ([1x18](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/018.html) and [1x19](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/019.html)) *"maybe"*
- ["Babylon Squared"](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/020.html) (1x20) *"beware it has aged badly"*
- ["Chrysalis"](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/022.html) (1x22)

Both of those lists, obviously, also provide suggestions for episodes to catch in the later series, as well, though the umtsb5 list predates the end of season 3.